# search via a Term query using NEST client for elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am having difficulty searching for documents by a specific term. Every time I do i get zero results.

Here is a code example:

```cs
var customers = new List<SampleCustomer>();
customers.Add(new SampleCustomer(){id=1,firstname="John", surname="Smith", country = "UK", sex = "Male", age=30});
customers.Add(new SampleCustomer(){id=2,firstname="Steve", surname="Jones",  country ="UK", sex = "Male", age=22});
customers.Add(new SampleCustomer(){id=3,firstname="Kate", surname="Smith",  country ="UK", sex = "Female", age=50});
customers.Add(new SampleCustomer(){id=4,firstname="Mark", surname="Jones",  country ="USA", sex = "Male", age=45});
customers.Add(new SampleCustomer(){id=5,firstname="Emma", surname="Jonson",  country ="USA", sex = "Female", age=25});
customers.Add(new SampleCustomer(){id=6,firstname="Tom", surname="Jones",  country ="France", sex = "Male", age=30});
customers.Add(new SampleCustomer(){id=7,firstname="Liz", surname="Web",  country ="France", sex = "Female", age=45});

foreach (var customer in customers)
{
    _elasticClient.DeleteById("sample", "SampleCustomers",customer.id);
    _elasticClient.Index(customer, "sample", "SampleCustomers" , customer.id);
}
```

using this index I can query the customers with the first name of smith using the query string filter

```cs
var queryByQueryString = _elasticClient.Search<SampleCustomer>(s =>
           s.From(0).Size(10).Type("SampleCustomers")
           .Query(q => q.QueryString(qs => qs.Query("Smith").OnField("surname"))));
```

but if I try search for customers using the term filer I get zero results

```cs
var queryByTerm = _elasticClient.Search<SampleCustomer>(s =>
            s.From(0).Size(10).Type("SampleCustomers")
            .Query(q => q.Term(p => p.surname, "Smith")));
```

I dont know what im doing wrong? In the example above I want to make sure that my query only returns results where the surname exactly equals "Smith" and that if someone had a double-barrelled surname such as "Smith Jones" they would not appear in the results.

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to know for sure without seeing your mapping, but your problem might just be case-sensitivity. If the `"surname"` field is using the default [`standard` analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) (which it is unless you specified one in the mapping), the tokens are modified to lower-case. So there will be a `"smith"` token but no `"Smith"`. When you use a query string query, your query text will be analyzed (with the `standard` analyzer unless you provide one) and so the search text gets modified to `"smith"` which matches a token. But a [`term` filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html) does NOT do any analysis, and the filter text `"Smith"` does not match any tokens so no results are returned.

If this is indeed your problem, then this should return results:

```cs
var queryByTerm = _elasticClient.Search<SampleCustomer>(s =>
            s.From(0).Size(10).Type("SampleCustomers")
            .Query(q => q.Term(p => p.surname, "smith")));
```

Alternatively, you could set the `"surname"` field to `"index": "not_analyzed"` in your mapping (will require a re-index), and so tokens will not be lower-cased, and your term filter with the text `"Smith"` will match.

Comment: Thanks yes the lower case has worked. I cant get it to work with Smith though. I did add the not_analysed attribute to the surname property on the Sample customer class but it hasnt changed anything.
e.g.

    [ElasticProperty( Index = FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed)]
    public string surname { get; set; }

Comment: Did you re-index with the new mapping? Are you sure it worked? Could you post the mapping? It's hard to know what's wrong without seeing the mapping. I'm not that familiar with Nest, but you can get the mapping just by hitting http://[endpoint]/[index_name]/_mapping